# Reading chars from multiple files in C

Tags: c, file, file-io, stdin

I am trying to read all the chars that are in different files. For example, by calling `myprogram < file1 file2`.

My approach is the following:

```
void do_read(FILE * file){
char ch;

    while (ch != EOF) {
        ch = getc(file);


        printf("%c\n", ch);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int i = 1;
    FILE * fp = NULL;

    if (argc < 1) {
        //Error. No file given
printf("Error");
    }
    else {
        // cycle through all files in command line arguments and read them
        for (i=1; i < argc; i++) {
            if ((fp = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL) {
                printf("Failed to open file.\n");
            }
            else {
                do_read(fp);
                fclose(fp);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But whenever I try to run it even as `myprogram < file1` (with only 1 argument) it doesn't output anything. Not even the `printf("Error")`.

Can anyone help me to fix my code please? What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach?

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: The first arg will be the program name, you will never have `argc < 1`.

Comment: Thank you for the observation. Will correct my code!

Comment: With `char ch; while (ch != EOF) {`, `ch` is not yet defined, so what do you expected `while (ch != EOF)` to do?

Answer (score 2):

`myprogram < file1` is essentially shorthand for `cat file1 | myprogram`, that is, your program would want to read stdin to get the contents of that file. The invocation you want is `myprogram file1 file2`.

Also, your do_read function is broken, because it'll even print the char when it *is* `EOF`. Instead of checking before you get, check *when* you get:

```
void do_read(FILE * file){
    char ch = '\0';

    while (ch != EOF) {
        ch = getc(file);
        printf("%c\n", ch);
    }
}
/* Becomes: */
void do_read(FILE * file){
    char ch = '\0';

    while ((ch = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c\n", ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: @CesarA:  Notice the first sentences of this answer.  You must *not* invoke the program with a `<` on the command line.  That redirects stdin to the first file, but since the program does *not* read stdin, that file is skipped.

Comment: you are right! by the way... do you happen to know how to set all the elements of an array to null? As in to delete the values of it after I use them! Thanks for your help

Comment: @CesarA 1. Setting an array element to null does **not** 'delete the item' — may be it does in Java, but not in C. 2. Do not add requests in comments; ask a new question instead.

Comment: Use `int ch`  as `getch()` returns 257 different values.  Attempting to store 1 of 257 different values into a `char` will break something.